# Count the records in a temp variable table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to count the total records in a variable table, this is because I am also going to need to store the table in a sorted way. The entire point behind my problem is a query that will calculate the 90th percentile. I got this few steps from the internet: Order all the values in the data set from smallest to largest.

Multiply k percent by the total number of values, n.

This number is called the index.

If the index obtained in Step 2 is not a whole number, round it up to the nearest whole number and go to Step 4a. If the index obtained in Step 2 is a whole number, go to Step 4b.

4a.Count the values in your data set from left to right (from the smallest to the largest value) until you reach the number indicated by Step 3.

The corresponding value in your data set is the kth percentile.

4b.Count the values in your data set from left to right until you reach the number indicated by Step 2.

My error...

```
1.DECLARE @TempMarks TABLE
2.( 
3.  mark float
4.); 

5.INSERT @TempMarks 
6.SELECT mark 
7.FROM Marks 
8.ORDER BY mark ASC

9.DECLARE @index float
10.SET @index = 90 * COUNT( (SELECT (mark) FROM @TempMarks ))
```

...comes in at line 10 :

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
SET @index = 90 * (SELECT COUNT(mark) FROM @TempMarks)
```